# How to install tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having some difficulties in installing TensorFlow on my computer.

My OS: Windows 8

My Python version: 3.7 (64-bit)

I used pip install Tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Should I copy its commands to cmd? Or I should change some details of them accordingly?

For example:

I tried running code:

```
pip3 install -U pip virtualenv
```

Here is what I get:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\A>virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
```

What does it mean by "the path does not exist"? I tried changing "python3 ." to "python3.7 .", but it doesn't work out.

Even tho the first command didn't work out, it seems the pip, python, and virtualenv are installed on my PC.

Here is the issue I have when I try to download Tensorflow:

I tried running code:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\A>.\venv\Scripts\activate
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\A>pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\
python37\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)

C:\Users\A>
C:\Users\A>pip list  # show packages installed within the virtual environment
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.0.2
setuptools 45.1.0
virtualenv 16.7.9
wheel      0.34.2

C:\Users\A>pip install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (355.8 MB)
     |                                | 788 kB 3.2 kB/s eta 1 day, 6:26:40ERROR:
 Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py", l
ine 457, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py", l
ine 501, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\socket.py", line 5
89, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1071
, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ssl.py", line 929,
 in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\commands\install.py", line 331, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=hashes,
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 287, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 159, in unpack_http_url
    link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 303, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\utils\ui.py", line 160, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_internal\network\utils.py", line 39, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\contextlib.py", li
ne 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\
_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files
.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

C:\Users\A>https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949
```

How can I install Tensorflow? Thank you!

**Update 1:**

When I change 'python 3' to 'python', and 'pip3' to 'pip', the first few command lines work out.

However, I still can't download Tensorflow.

A bit more has been downloaded this time:

```
(venv) C:\Users\A> pip install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (355.8 MB)
     |█                               | 8.4 MB 10.0 kB/s eta 9:40:28ERROR: Exce
ption:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line
 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line
 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.p
y", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\http\client.py", l
ine 457, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\http\client.py", l
ine 501, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\socket.py", line 5
89, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\ssl.py", line 1071
, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\ssl.py", line 929,
 in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", li
ne 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", li
ne 331, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line
 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line
 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line
 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py",
line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=hashes,
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py",
line 287, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py",
line 159, in unpack_http_url
    link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py",
line 303, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 160,
in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line
39, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line
 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line
 529, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\contextlib.py", li
ne 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line
 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files
.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

(venv) C:\Users\A>
```

**Update 2:**

I used the following command line:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple tensorflow
```

Much more was downloaded.

Here is the new error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<2.2.0
,>=2.1.0 (from tensorflow) (from versions: 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0,
 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 2.0.0,
2.0.1, 2.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0 (from tensor
flow)

C:\Users\A>
```

Do I need a different version of Tensorflow?

Comment: Did you try 'python' instead of 'python3'?

Comment: This works. When I use 'python' for 'python3', and 'pip' for 'pip3', the first few commands work out.

Comment: as an advice on windows it's generally better to work with anaconda.

Comment: Check these workarounds for your Update 2 error https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36380

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands to install TensorFlow inside virtual environment.

1) upgrade pip3:
  **python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip**
2) Install virtual env
   **pip3 install virtualenv**
3) You can then create a virtualenv using the full path of python3 like this:
  **virtualenv -p /home/example_username/opt/python-3.6.2/bin/python3 venv**
4) Activate virtual env
  **source venv/bin/activate**
5) install tensorflow
  **pip3 install tensorflow**

Answer (score 0):

please note this error message.

```
raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files
.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

It seems that you can't connect to `files.pythonhosted.org`. You can visit this url: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files to down `tensorflow-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` first. And then use `pip install <name>.whl` to install it.

More:
If you are in China, you can use bellow command to install `tensorflow` from tsinghua University.

```
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple tensorflow
```